# Reached question limit while asking on meta?

Tags: discussion

I'm finding many catch-22s and  I have to struggle to understand how to create a high quality question. I then ask, and get downvoted and then get question blocked again?

### Question

What's up with the catch-22s lately?

Sidenote:

I'm just writing a  practice question on paper and planning on posting it Friday to give time into research for higher quality. Learning from my mistakes to prevent question ban. I'm also learn better with trial and error because multiple times reading still confuses me.

Comment: Not a very good algorithm. If you ask me. (no pun intended)

Comment: It's the algorithm we have and it mostly works as designed. It's by no means perfect (cf. quite a few discussions here on Meta) but it seems to work for many users. You can shortcut by checking out well-received questions and reflect on what they do differently. Be wary, though: simple, "catchy" questions do tend to accumulate upvotes even if they are not particularly good, and we have FAQs under [reference-question] which are more general than we'd usually want a question to be.

Comment: @TravisWells I'm not exactly sure what you're asking here, but note that the question ban on main is completely independent of your posts on meta. You have received the question ban by asking multiple poor questions on main. The only way to lift the ban, as described in the [help center](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), is to improve the poorly received questions you have already asked, or wait 6 months and ask a good question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to lift your ban by improving all your questions. Start from these with score < 0 and put on hold. If you are able to reopen question, it means that you are on a good track.

Improve one at the time, if problem persists I will give you comment, if it is ok, I will cast reopen vote.

Remember that invalidating existing answers is not a way to go.